# Unity Library: Android GPS Access Issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, android-gps

I am having issues with the unity library when it comes to accessing GPS Data from my phone. I have debugged it and it goes to  LocationServiceStatus.stopped. But I get 0's for coordinates so I don't know why I am getting 0's and what would be calling that issue. I have also have tested this on my phone and the pop-up asking to request permission to access my location works as well but still get 0's for my coordinates. Any help on this would be appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class GPSLocation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI GPSStatus;
    public TextMeshProUGUI latitudeValue;
    public TextMeshProUGUI longitudeValue;
    public TextMeshProUGUI altitudeValue;
    public TextMeshProUGUI horizontalAccuracyValue;
    public TextMeshProUGUI TimestampValue;



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(GPSLoc());
    }


    IEnumerator GPSLoc()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        // No permission handling needed in Editor
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
        if (!UnityEngine.Android.Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(UnityEngine.Android.Permission.FineLocation))
        {
            UnityEngine.Android.Permission.RequestUserPermission(UnityEngine.Android.Permission.FineLocation);
            UnityEngine.Android.Permission.RequestUserPermission(UnityEngine.Android.Permission.CoarseLocation);
            GPSStatus.text = "GRANTED";
        }
        else
        {
            GPSStatus.text = "No Access";
            Debug.LogFormat("Android Does not have access");
            yield break;
        }

        //if (!UnityEngine.Android.Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(UnityEngine.Android.Permission.Camera))
        //{
        //    UnityEngine.Android.Permission.RequestUserPermission(UnityEngine.Android.Permission.Camera);
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    Debug.LogFormat("Android Does not have camera access");
        //    yield break;
        //}

        // First, check if user has location service enabled
        //if (!UnityEngine.Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
        //{
        //    // TODO Failure
        //    Debug.LogFormat("Android and Location not enabled");
        //    yield break;
        //}
#endif
        Input.location.Start();
        int maxWait = 50;
        while(Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0)
        {
            GPSStatus.text = "Initializing";
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            maxWait--;
        }
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        int editorMaxWait = 15;
        while (UnityEngine.Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Stopped && editorMaxWait > 0)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);
            editorMaxWait--;
        }
#endif

        if (maxWait < 1)
        {
            GPSStatus.text = "Time Out";
            yield break;
        }

        if(Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed)
        {
          GPSStatus.text = "Unable to determine Device Location";
          yield break;
        }

        else
        {
            //Access Granted
            GPSStatus.text = "Running";
            InvokeRepeating("UpdateGPSData",0.5f,1f);
        }


    }

    private void UpdateGPSData()
    {
        if(Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Running)
        {
            //Access granted to GPS
            GPSStatus.text = "Running";
            latitudeValue.text = Input.location.lastData.latitude.ToString();
            longitudeValue.text = Input.location.lastData.longitude.ToString();
            altitudeValue.text = Input.location.lastData.altitude.ToString();
            horizontalAccuracyValue.text = Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy.ToString();
            TimestampValue.text = Input.location.lastData.timestamp.ToString();
        }

        else if(Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing)
        {
            //service is initializing
            GPSStatus.text = "Initializing";
        }
        
        else if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed)
        {
            GPSStatus.text = "Failed";
        }

        else
        {
            GPSStatus.text = "Stop";
            latitudeValue.text = Input.location.lastData.latitude.ToString();
            longitudeValue.text = Input.location.lastData.longitude.ToString();
            altitudeValue.text = Input.location.lastData.altitude.ToString();
            horizontalAccuracyValue.text = Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy.ToString();
            TimestampValue.text = Input.location.lastData.timestamp.ToString();
        }
    }

}
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class GPSLocation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI GPSStatus;
    public TextMeshProUGUI latitudeValue;
    public TextMeshProUGUI longitudeValue;
    public TextMeshProUGUI altitudeValue;
    public TextMeshProUGUI horizontalAccuracyValue;
    public TextMeshProUGUI TimestampValue;



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(GPSLoc());
    }


    IEnumerator GPSLoc()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        // No permission handling needed in Editor
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
        if (!UnityEngine.Android.Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(UnityEngine.Android.Permission.FineLocation))
        {
            UnityEngine.Android.Permission.RequestUserPermission(UnityEngine.Android.Permission.FineLocation);
            UnityEngine.Android.Permission.RequestUserPermission(UnityEngine.Android.Permission.CoarseLocation);
            GPSStatus.text = "GRANTED";
        }
        else
        {
            GPSStatus.text = "No Access";
            Debug.LogFormat("Android Does not have access");
            yield break;
        }

        //if (!UnityEngine.Android.Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(UnityEngine.Android.Permission.Camera))
        //{
        //    UnityEngine.Android.Permission.RequestUserPermission(UnityEngine.Android.Permission.Camera);
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    Debug.LogFormat("Android Does not have camera access");
        //    yield break;
        //}

        // First, check if user has location service enabled
        //if (!UnityEngine.Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
        //{
        //    // TODO Failure
        //    Debug.LogFormat("Android and Location not enabled");
        //    yield break;
        //}
#endif
        Input.location.Start();
        int maxWait = 50;
        while(Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0)
        {
            GPSStatus.text = "Initializing";
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            maxWait--;
        }
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        int editorMaxWait = 15;
        while (UnityEngine.Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Stopped && editorMaxWait > 0)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);
            editorMaxWait--;
        }
#endif

        if (maxWait < 1)
        {
            GPSStatus.text = "Time Out";
            yield break;
        }

        if(Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed)
        {
          GPSStatus.text = "Unable to determine Device Location";
          yield break;
        }

        else
        {
            //Access Granted
            GPSStatus.text = "Running";
            InvokeRepeating("UpdateGPSData",0.5f,1f);
        }


    }

    private void UpdateGPSData()
    {
        if(Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Running)
        {
            //Access granted to GPS
            GPSStatus.text = "Running";
            latitudeValue.text = Input.location.lastData.latitude.ToString();
            longitudeValue.text = Input.location.lastData.longitude.ToString();
            altitudeValue.text = Input.location.lastData.altitude.ToString();
            horizontalAccuracyValue.text = Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy.ToString();
            TimestampValue.text = Input.location.lastData.timestamp.ToString();
        }

        else if(Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing)
        {
            //service is initializing
            GPSStatus.text = "Initializing";
        }
        
        else if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed)
        {
            GPSStatus.text = "Failed";
        }

        else
        {
            GPSStatus.text = "Stop";
            latitudeValue.text = Input.location.lastData.latitude.ToString();
            longitudeValue.text = Input.location.lastData.longitude.ToString();
            altitudeValue.text = Input.location.lastData.altitude.ToString();
            horizontalAccuracyValue.text = Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy.ToString();
            TimestampValue.text = Input.location.lastData.timestamp.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```